# How can I install node.js successfully on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I installed nodejs via apt, as well as the nodejs-legacy package, trying to take a quick look at this platform.  Wasn't going to be that easy.

Anyway, the search facility did not work, and I assume this means that the installation was somehow incomplete.

Googling suggested that it might have something to do with the permissions in the ~/.npm directory.  I doubt this, but I tried to chown this directory recursively to my user as well as running the command "npm search" with sudo, both with the same result.

Updating with extra information:

Installation procedure:

```
$sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy // the latter makes a symlink
```

Output from running command:

```
$ npm search
npm ERR! TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
npm ERR!     at Function.keys (native)
npm ERR!     at stripData (/usr/share/npm/lib/search.js:89:28)
npm ERR!     at Array.map (native)
npm ERR!     at filter (/usr/share/npm/lib/search.js:73:6)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/search.js:63:21
npm ERR!     at RegClient.requestAll_ (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-  client   /lib/get.js:66:5)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client /lib/get.js:58:19)
npm ERR!     at fs.js:268:14
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/x/temp/npm-debug.log npm

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.6-031106-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "search"
npm ERR! cwd /home/x/
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! type called_on_non_object
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/x/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Logfile info:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'search' ]
2 info using npm@1.2.18
3 info using node@v0.10.15
4 warn Building the local index for the first time, please be patient
5 verbose url raw /-/all
6 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './-/all' ]
7 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
8 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 10:56:16
9 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
10 http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
11 error TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
11 error     at Function.keys (native)
11 error     at stripData (/usr/share/npm/lib/search.js:89:28)
11 error     at Array.map (native)
11 error     at filter (/usr/share/npm/lib/search.js:73:6)
11 error     at /usr/share/npm/lib/search.js:63:21
11 error     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:89:14
11 error     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
11 error     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
12 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
12 error     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
12 error or use
12 error     reportbug --attach /home/x/npm-debug.log npm
13 error System Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
14 error command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "search"
15 error cwd /home/x
16 error node -v v0.10.15
17 error npm -v 1.2.18
18 error type called_on_non_object
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How do I interpret and remedy this error?  I wasn't able to get anything out of this debugging info.

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: ubuntu or linux user might be a better place for this question?

Comment: It is unclear from your question, but did you install simply following the directions [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#wiki-ubuntu-mint-elementary-os)? I ask because I'm not following why you installed X 'as well as' X'. It sounds like you might have trouble because you may effectively have two versions of node installed and conflicting somehow. My assumption is you attempted this install recently, and 0.10.15 is from last July. I have 0.10.25 from when I did it on Ubuntu within the past month or so.

Comment: It is true that I just did it, on Ubuntu 13.10, and as it is in the repository it should work.  Essentially your link says it is enough to use the command I used above, but I did not try to add other extra repositories for apt just for node.js.  The legacy package only symlinks, I think, removing it has no effect.  Strange that you have a different version of node.js from apt, as my databases are updated.  What Ubuntu are you running?  Experimental packages?

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. I followed the instructions pointed at by barry-johnson (the extended version, not the single command). `npm search` works for me now (thanks).

Answer (score 1):

Although "ppa:chris-lea/node.js" does a great job ( answer by Moxley Stratton is fine), I am no fan of upgrade cycles in my dev environment, having to depend on a third-party PPA, having different names of binary files(nodejs, node) which seem to mess with my scripts.

I download the node precompiled tar.gz from http://nodejs.org/dist/ and maintain by own folder with different versions(prod, dev).
Maintain a symlink in PATH for node and npm. My system (64 bit) E.g

```
cd node_base_folder
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.24/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar -zvxf node-v0.10.24-linux-x64.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s node_base_folder/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64/bin/node
ln -s node_base_folder/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64/bin/npm
```

Whenever you want to move to new node version. Just follow above steps (after changing version)

Comment: I agree with you, it should be able to install "natively" under Ubuntu.  If it doesn't there must be an error in the packaging system somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the directions on the ["Installing Node.js via package manager" wiki page, section "Ubuntu, Mint, elementary OS"](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint), under "Obtaining a recent version of Node...", copied here:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make nodejs
```

However, nodejs-legacy does not install for me either:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs-legacy
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 119 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe nodejs-legacy all 0.10.15~dfsg1-4 [15.4 kB]
Fetched 15.4 kB in 0s (243 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs-legacy.
(Reading database ... 63176 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nodejs-legacy (from .../nodejs-legacy_0.10.15~dfsg1-4_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs-legacy_0.10.15~dfsg1-4_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz', which is also in package nodejs 0.10.26-1chl1~saucy1
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs-legacy_0.10.15~dfsg1-4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```